# Error while adding main title with subscript in gridExtra

Tags: r, ggplot2, subscript, gridextra

I am trying to arrange a few plots generated by `ggplot2`using the `gridExtra` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(main="CO2Exp", p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)
```

When I try to have a main title, the follwing works fine.

```
grid.arrange(main="CO2Exp", p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)
```

But when I try with `expression` to get a subscript,

```
grid.arrange(main=expression(paste(CO[2], "Exp")), p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in valid.data(rep(units, length.out = length(x)), data) : 
  no 'grob' supplied for 'grobwidth/height' unit
```

How to fix this?

I am using `R`_3.1.3, `gridExtra`_0.9.1 and `ggplot2`_1.0.1

Comment: grid.arrange makes a crude test for `is.character`, which are passed to textGrob, but expressions don't pass the test. The workaround is to pass a textGrob directly as shown below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `textGrob` explicitly:

```
grid.arrange(main = textGrob(label = expression(paste(CO[2], "Exp"))), 
             p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol=2)
```

**Edit** (16/07/2015): with `gridExtra` >= 2.0.0, the `main` parameter has been renamed `top`. See `?arrangeGrob` for details.

Comment: Aaaa, beat my by seconds. :)